# 2010 Access SQL insert, setting fields based on existence of matching row in different table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I'm new at this, so please bear with me.

I am trying to INSERT all rows from `[Excel Monthly Detail]` into a table and set two different fields to a `"Y"` depending on if there are any rows in `[Model Detail]` or `[Excel Account Performance]` with a matching Ticker.

These are only the three fields in `[Current Mode/Account Tickers]`.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Current Model/Account Tickers] 
    (Ticker, [Current Model], [Current Account])
Select (Ticker) From [Excel Monthly Detail],
Select (Iif (DCount(“*”,”[Model Detail]”, “Ticker = “ & [Ticker])>0,”Y”))
      From [Model Detail],
Select (Iif(DCount(“*”,”[Excel Account Performance”,”Ticker +” & [Ticker])>0,”Y”))
      From [Excel Account Performance];
```

I receive the following error:

```
"Number of query values and destination fields are not the same"
```

The resulting table should look something like this:

```
TICKER          [CURRENT MODEL]       [CURRENT ACCOUNT]
ABC                   Y
DEF                                           Y
GHI
JKL                   Y                       Y
```

Where -

- `"ABC"` also occurs in `[Current Model]`
- `"DEF"` occurs in `[Excel Account Performance]`
- `"GHI"` does not occur in either
- `"JKL"` occurs in both.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` between your `[Excel Monthly Detail]` table and your other tables is appropriate for this situation, since you are looking to output the `Ticker` for all records in this table, but only values for those records in your other tables with a matching `Ticker` value.

I would therefore suggest something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO [Current Model/Account Tickers] (Ticker, [Current Model], [Current Account])
SELECT 
    [Excel Monthly Detail].Ticker, 
    iif([Model Detail].Ticker IS NULL,NULL,"Y")
    iif([Excel Account Performance].Ticker IS NULL,NULL,"Y")
FROM
(
    [Excel Monthly Detail]
    LEFT JOIN [Model Detail] 
    ON [Excel Monthly Detail].Ticker = [Model Detail].Ticker
)
LEFT JOIN [Excel Account Performance] 
ON [Excel Monthly Detail].Ticker = [Excel Account Performance].Ticker
```

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, it placed duplicate Tickers in the new table.  Any suggestion on how to not get duplicates?  There could be several duplicates in [Model Detail] or [Excel Account Performance].  But it did seem to set the "Y" correctly.

Comment: I changed the SELECT to SELECT DISTINCT and that gave me the results I wanted.  Thank you for your help!